Is there a way to make a video automatically play without controls and volume with GitHub?
so I was adding the following code below for a embed video iframe.



<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay" muted>


  <source src="//valodokagames.github.io/media/videos/valodoka_ads/lv_0_20240913182631.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

</video>


The video is muted without audio and the video controls are also removed. Its kind of like a video advertisement, sort of.
But when I test it from my phone when I view it on my GitHub website, it doesn't work. Is there a solution to this?
Thank you!

Looks like it's auto playing for me. Maybe you want to add the loop attribute?

Also autoplaying for me on Firefox 130.

Try adding playsinline to your  tag:
<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay" muted playsinline>
